# Downtime if increasing memory for Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I would like to increase memory for my Google Cloud SQL instance but I am unable to find the downtime for the same. On this page https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq I can find downtime for storage (zero downtime) and CPU (few minutes) but nothing for memory.

Can somebody help me understand if there is downtime associated if I want to increase my RAM for the instance.

Comment: Changing the memory involves a similar operation to change vCPUs. In my experience, less than five minutes of downtime. However, as the FAQ mentions, for large, heavily used instances, downtime can be up to an hour.

Comment: Thanks, John, I thought so. I will be doing it soon, so will update the answer with my experience

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I upgraded my RAM and it seems that the downtime is about 2 minutes, roughly the amount to restart my underlying machine.

I hope this helps somebody